# Permutations of 0 and 1

Tags: c

How can I write a C program, where given my `n` number (that goes from 1 to 10), I have as a result a permutation of 0 and 1.
For example, let's say `n = 2`. My output must be something like: `00`; `01`; `10`; `11`. And so on, for `n = 3` there will be 8 possible permutations `(000, 001, 010, 100, 101, 110, 011, 111)`.

I have some restrictions for the code:

- My only possible library is stdio.h (given that, math.h is not allowed);
- Continue and break are not allowed;
- Each function must have one return;
- Bitwise operators are also not allowed;

Thanks for now.

EDIT: Actually, the program is a lot bigger than this, I've achieved all the other parts but I can't solve this part.

Comment: where is your code example?

Comment: You're totally asking for help with your homework. At a bare minimum, you should try it yourself and see where you get stuck before coming to SO to ask for help.

Comment: Notice a pattern with those `1`s and `0`s? See if you can related binary numbers to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PROC_BEGIN \
    ++i;                                              \
    for(char bit = '0' ; i != n &&  bit < '2'; ++bit){\
        bits[i] = bit;                                \
        if(i+1 == n)                                  \
            puts(bits);                               \
    /**/

#define PROC_END \
    }            \
    --i;         \
    /**/

int main(void){
    char bits[10+1] = {0};
    int n, i = -1;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_BEGIN
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    PROC_END
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is ugly but clever

Answer (score 1):

Here's my recursive crack at it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void permute_iter(int left, char str[])
{
    if(left>=0) {
        str[left] = '0';
        permute_iter(left-1, str);
        str[left] = '1';
        permute_iter(left-1, str);
    } else {
        puts(str);
    }
}

void permute(int times)
{
    char str[times+1];
    str[times] = '\0';
    permute_iter(times-1, str);
}

int main()
{
    permute(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Each function must have one return;_

Comment: Maybe you can figure out how to add one :P